# Sqlite performance as website traffic grows

Tags: mysql, sqlite

So I have this website I'm about to release, and during development i used Sqlite with the intention of migrating to MySQL before moving to production.

I've just migrated all my data (about 40K rows) to a MySQL database and tested performance against Sqlite. Surprisingly, Sqlite performed about twice as fast!

With that in mind, I'm considering just sticking to Sqlite as it's easier to handle. The only things that I'm worried about is if Sqlite performance will get worse as website traffic grows, and if so, will it get a lot worse or just a little slower.

By the way, I'm aware that Sqlite has trouble with multiple writes at the same time, but that wont be a problem since that database is for reading only.

Comment: You're probably fine if the db is read-only. As traffic grows, whether using MySQL or SQLite, you should cache the data anyway to something unrelated like memcached or Redis.

Comment: 40k rows should not be a problem at all for MySQL. But if you don't have good indexes then Sqlite might run faster. With good indexes, MySQL should be super-fast until your data & queries get "too big", which is a rather subjective/nebulous idea that depends on many factors. MySQL on a decent server with a decent configuration will cache quite well automatically, but indexes are the key.

Comment: @manassehkatz Neither MySQL nor SQLite will run well without indexes on a large amount of data, and both will be affected in approximately the same way by indexes. So while this might be something to look into, it does not affect the choice of DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't do any fancy table/record locking (it has only a global database lock), so it will be faster if the locks aren't actually needed. (With read-only accesses, and probably only a single user (the web server), there will never be conflicts.)

Furthermore, SQLite is a library that is part of the web server process, so it is likely to be more efficient than a database server running in a separate process.

As long as there will not be any writes, this behaviour will not change.

(See [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).)